# PHP get file name from URL stripping extension and image dimesion

Tags: php, preg-replace, preg-match

Following is one of the dynamically generated variable i have
http://www.niresh.guru/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/We-are-all-visual-creators-469x1024.jpg

I want to get final output of filename stripping extension jpg and image dimesion 469x1024 and final name in lowercase
this is the final output im expecting 
we-are-all-visual-creators
Note hyphen before the image dimension also needed to be removed

I need a common function to strip image dimension and image extensions like jpg, png, jpeg and tiff  (case insensitive)

Im using my iPhone to ask this question i have tried a few php by researching in internet, due to powercut I can't use my mac these are all the info i can provide thanks.

please do not downrate if you have any questions comment

Comment: Question isn't well formatted because i have no option to format when asking on iPhone i realized this after posting if possible please mod my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is that what you want:

```
$url = " http://www.niresh.guru/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/We-are-all-visual-creators-469x1024.jpg";
preg_match('~^.+/([\w-]+)-(\d+x\d+)(\.\w+)$~', $url, $match);
print_r($match);
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] =>  http://www.niresh.guru/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/We-are-all-visual-creators-469x1024.jpg
    [1] => We-are-all-visual-creators
    [2] => 469x1024
    [3] => .jpg
)
```

Comment: Yes almost, i just want "We-are-all-visual-creators" in lower case finally

Answer (score 0):

Here Just try this piece of code:

```
<?php
$path = "http://www.niresh.guru/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/We-are-all-visual-creators-469x1024.jpg";
$filename = substr(strrchr($path, "/"), 1);
echo $filename;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use something like this:

```
    $tmpParam=explode('/2016/06/', trim($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']));
    $imgname=$tmpParam[1];
```

It will return you image name and than explode image name again to get what you need.

Comment: Hi /2016/06/ clould also changed as those urls are generated when uploading, after a month this code won't work

Comment: Than just $tmpParam=explode('/', trim($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])) and get the last param from loop like this
$imgname=$tmpParam[count($tmpParam)-1]
It will return last in path and it will always will be image name in your case